# How to focus a Pivot on a specific PivotItem from the ViewModel with Caliburn

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone, caliburn.micro

Using the Caliburn MVVM pattern for an Universal App (WP8.1 project) I want, from code, to focus a PivotPage on a specific PivotItem, from the Caliburn ModelView of that page. Note that sometime I am not interested to use the Conductor class because all the PivotItems of MyPivot page have a common DataSource so I think that in this case it is useless to have multiple ViewModel for each PivotItem.

What I want to do in MyPivotViewModel is what it should be done in the code-behind in that way:

```
        pvMyPivot.SelectedIndex = 2;
```

or

```
        pvMyPivot.SelectedItem = Pivot2Name;
```

Any suggestion and example code is appreciated ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can bind to SelectedIndex or the SelectionChanged event or both if you need from the viewmodel... Just have to replicate the event signature, for SelectedIndex would be an integer property.

```
private int _pivotindex;
public int PivotIndex{
    get{ return _pivotindex;}
    set{
         _pivotindex = value;
         NotifyOfPropertyChanged();
    }
}

public void SelectionChanged( SelectionChangedEventArgs e){

}
```

then in your xaml you would

```
<Pivot  SelectedIndex="{Binding PivotIndex, Mode=TwoWay}"
        cm:Message.Attach="[Event SelectionChanged] = [Action SelectionChanged($eventArgs)]"    />
```

for example...

The other answer would probably work swapping out the Generic Type for Pivot, but would probably have to get modified from there to incorporate the changes to accommodate WinRT as opposed to Silverlight in the Panorama's case...